Magento 2 SimiCart - Magento 2 Mobile App Builder
We are using Magento 2.4.2-p2 version with SimiCart - Magento 2 Mobile App Builder
We are struggling from where category_id is coming
File name - app/code/Simi/Simiconnector/Model/ResourceModel/Productlist/ProductlistCollection.php
File function -
$collection = $simiObjectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect($simiObjectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Config')
->getProductAttributes())
->addMinimalPrice()
->addFinalPrice()
->addTaxPercents()
->addUrlRewrite();

when we print SQL query then category_id is coming from where it is coming ?
Debugging that part -
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
die;

this is the SQL query we are getting -

SELECT e.*, price_index.price, price_index.tax_class_id,
price_index.final_price, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
price_index.min_price) AS minimal_price, price_index.min_price,
price_index.max_price, price_index.tier_price,
cat_index.position AS cat_index_position FROM
catalog_product_entity AS e INNER JOIN
catalog_product_index_price AS price_index ON
price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id
= 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1' INNER JOIN catalog_category_product_index_store2 AS cat_index ON
cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=2 AND
cat_index.category_id=29 WHERE (e.created_in <= '1677618002') AND (e.updated_in > '1677618002')

We are struggling from From where category id is coming.
Does anyone know from where category id is coming ?

In the SQL query you're seeing, the category_id is coming from the catalog_category_product_index_store2 table, which is used to associate products with categories for specific stores in Magento. This table is part of Magento's indexing system and is specific to the store you are working with (store_id=2 in this case).
The part of the SQL query that involves this is:
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product_index_store2 AS cat_index ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id
AND cat_index.store_id=2
AND cat_index.category_id=29

This INNER JOIN is pulling the category association for each product from the catalog_category_product_index_store2 table. The category_id=29 refers to a specific category ID for products in store 2.
In Magento, product collections are automatically filtered by category if they are related to category pages or layered navigation where the product-to-category relationship is essential. This can happen even if you didn't explicitly add the category_id filter to your custom collection logic.
To trace where exactly this is being injected, it could be part of the catalog layer code, or added dynamically by observers or plugins depending on the context in which the collection is being used (such as category views or category-related modules). You might want to check if any observers or plugins are modifying the collection by listening for catalog_block_product_list_collection or catalog_category_load_after events, or by reviewing any around plugins on the collection.
Let me know if you need further assistance in narrowing down where this logic is being added!

i checked with catalog_block_product_list_collection and catalog_category_load_after, there is no events are calling.

Try disabling or commenting out individual methods in the $collection chain in ProductlistCollection.php to see if one of them is responsible for injecting the category_id
